# iOS7: How to add a fixed Search Bar like Contacts on iOS7?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

After I search a lot of questions and answers, no good result.
So I have to ask it here:

I want to add a Search Bar below the navigation bar.

This search bar should be fixed.
Just like contacts on iOS7 below.

[image: iOS7 contacts]
Can any one help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a view controller. It has a main view. Inside that main view is a search bar (UISearchBar) and, below that, a table view (UITableView).

Your view controller is embedded in a navigation controller (UINavigationController).

```
UINavigationController

MyViewController (UINavigationController) - child of the navigation controller

UIView - main view of MyViewController

|--- UISearchBar (subview of UIView)
|
|--- UITableView (another subview of UIView)
```

Comment: @honghao : as explain by matt, don't use a TableViewController, but a viewController. Of course you'll have to manage delegate for the UITableView by yourself.

Comment: @ArmandDOHM: Why not using a TableViewController?. i don´t see any reasons to avoid that.

Comment: @Daniel You could, but there is no need to (a UITableViewController does not do anything special for you), and you are not supposed to use a UITableViewController unless the UITableView is its main view. In this case, the table view is not the main view of the view controller.

Comment: Thanks for you guys! Since I am new to iOS develop, i simply add the SearchBar by using Storyboard. So, without code, I cannot implement this view. Now, I am trying to add searchBar and TableView programmatically.